# what are the guidelines to improve flume performance

Tags: apache, hadoop, flume, hortonworks-data-platform, bigdata

I have a use case where i have to transfer one million or more files in HDFS. File size can be vary from 10kb to 50kb.

I am using spool dir source and HDFS sink and file channel.

I am also using BLOB deserilizer as i do not want to break my source data.it should get transfer complete file as an event that i am able to achieve.
So far my flume agent design looks like this - [my flume agent design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpdvv.png)

Still i am not able to get good performance.

I also want to understand is hadoop cluster configuration can be helpful to improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no silver bullet for performance tuning. As usual, you will need to experiment and learn based on your data and infrastructure. The following articles discuss the various knobs (and general guidance) available to fine tune Flume performance:
[Cloudera - Flume Performance Tuning](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/how-to-do-apache-flume-performance-tuning-part-1/), [DZone - Flume Performance Tuning](https://dzone.com/articles/apache-flume-performance-tuning)